# What kind of plant is this and how do you take care of it

Tags: identification, plant-care

What is this plant and how do you care for it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is Kalenchoe blossfeldiana, a tropical succulent plant. It comes in many colours, and flowers on some are slightly larger than on others. Needs temperatures preferably around 65 deg F or more, and a sunny spot during winter is beneficial, though it does not like cold draughts. Images and further info https://thegardeningcook.com/kalanchoe-blossfeldiana-care/